# Rasterio doesn't show the coordinates when using "imshow "

Tags: python, coordinate-system, rasterio, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I have sentinel 2 image and I use rasterio to display it. I am using "imshow" to display it. when I display it, it doesn't show any coordinates:

```
src=rasterio.open('14072020.tif')

#Display the image 
plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
plt.imshow(src.read(4), cmap='gray')
plt.title('Gray Scale - Band 4')
```

[image]

I have ried to add it like this:

```
plt.imshow(src.read(4),transform=src.transform, cmap='gray')
```

but then I get error message:

> TypeError: 'transform' must be an instance of
> matplotlib.transforms.Transform, not a affine.Affine

the weird thing is that if I display 3 bands together it appears:

```
#RGB image
plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
show(src.read([4,3,2]),transform=src.transform,title='Image- bands 4,3,2 IN 0-255 Values',vmin=0,vmax=30000)
```

[image]

**Why is this happen? is there any way I can control add coordinates to the one band image?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your used `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow()` to show the first grayscale image, and `rasterio.plot.show()` for the second RGB one.

Use `show()` to display the first grayscale image (Band 4), too;

```
from rasterio.plot import show
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

src=rasterio.open('14072020.tif')
 
plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
show(src.read(4), transform=src.transform, title='Gray Scale - Band 4', cmap='gray')
```